# ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activ

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I made a python virtual environment using virtualenv, then installed django.

If I input 'django-admin --version' command, it outputs 1.11.13 when using virtualenv.

However, when I input ' python3.6 manage.py createsuperuser', it output below:

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in 
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in 
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

---

Thanks in advance to any suggestions!

---

more information here:

In a console of 'python3.6':

```
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use virtualenv you don't need to type ver. of python. I think python3.6 is /usr/bin/python3.6
just type:

> python manage.py createsuperuser

Comment: Thanks Ivan! But I got this errors:   File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax